# Error al publicar en IIS una Api hecha en asp netcore

Tags: api, iis, netcore

Estoy intentando publicar una api hecha en asp netcore web api, pero al ejecutar la url , esta me devuelve error 404.

1 .-Primero creo una carpeta en inetpub/wwwroot/ y la llamo ApiRestaurante

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

2.-Agrego un sitio web en IIS

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Selecciono el pool de conexion

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Selecciono la carpeta creada en inetpub/wwwroot/

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Asigno la configuración por defecto

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

cambio el puerto y presiono aceptar

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

3.-Publicar sitio en carpeta

Creamos perfil de publicación por carpeta

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Seleccionamos la carpeta creada en inetpub/wwwroot/ApiRestaurante

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Presionamos publicar

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Luego vamos a verificar los archivos en la carpeta

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y finalmente vamos a IIS a iniciar el sitio web api con swagger

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y aparece error 500
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

pongo la ruta de swagger llamando al controlador producto pero no funciona

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero si ejecuto la api desde local, esta si funciona
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Edita la pregunta y agrega toda información relacionada que has realizado en el IIS.

Comment: Saludos. La ubcación por default es dentro de **inetpub** en la carpeta **wwwroot**; lo anterior claro, a salvedad al *Agregar sitio web* indicaras en **Ruta de acceso física:**  la ruta (conforme lo que muestras) **wwwroot\ApiRestaurante**.

Comment: Hola buenas , acabo de actualizar y deje todos los pasos a realizar.

Comment: Swagger no va a funcionar en produccion.. salvo que toques la configuracion de swagger... es una medida de seguridad...

Comment: y para poder desplegar swagger en ambiente de desarrollo como lo podria hacer?

Comment: o como puedo apuntar a la ruta para poder probar los servicios?

Comment: como puedo resolver ese error 500?

Comment: como puedo probar los servicios de mi api si no puedo usar swagger?

Comment: Hola me podrian ayudar a identificar el por qué del error 500 que tengo?